# Confirming password using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need help in making a webpage.

When a user types the password, I want the statement 'the password is not the same' in my  part.
but I don't understand what is wrong with my code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title> Login Page </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="login_2.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
      <input type="hidden" name="hide" value="">
      <table class='center'>
        <tr><td>Login ID:</td><td><input type="text" name="ID"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr><br>
        <tr><td>confirm_password: </td><td><input type="password" name="confirm_password" onkeyup="test();"></td></tr><br>
        <tr><td><div id="pwd" style="height: 35px;"></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Full Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
      </form>
      <script>
        function test(){
          if(document.info.password.value != document.info.confirm_password.value){
            document.getElementById('pwd').innerHTML='wrong';
          }else{
            document.getElementbyId('pwd').innerHTML='continue';
          }
        }
      </script>
    </table>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td></tr>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.info` will most probably result in an error as there is no `info` on `document`.

Comment: Your `html` is malformed...  you close your form (`</form>`) before you close your table (`</table>`) and then have a `<tr>` after a `</table>`.

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("confirm_password")[0].value`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Seqfj/

Comment: Adding IDs to your inputs will make life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no id's on your input fields you can change document.info to document.getElementsByName

```
function test(){
    if(document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value != document.getElementById("confirm_password")[0].value){
            document.getElementById('pwd').innerHTML='wrong';
    }else{
            document.getElementbyId('pwd').innerHTML='continue';
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! not naming the form was the problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

see it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/3bjvk/1/)

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name=confirm_password]").keyup(function(){
    pass=$("input[name=password]").val();
    confpass=$("input[name=confirm_password]").val();
    if(pass==confpass)
        $("#pwd").html("same");
    else
        $("#pwd").html("wrong");
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

write name in form info ,will work

```
   <script>
    function test(){
            if(document.info.password.value != document.info.confirm_password.value){
                alert( "password doesn't match!" );
        document.info.Name.focus() ;

        return false; 
            }else{  

         return true; 
            }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: you did only one mistake,you are using document.info.password.value          write name in form <form name="info"/>